# Translate java to javascript like google inbox did

Tags: java, javascript, android, gwt

Lately I've read [a blog post](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com.es/2014/11/going-under-hood-of-inbox.html) that Google has used GWT for translating model classes in java to javascript for their Inbox android and web app. I'm evaluating if that would make sense to do for a next android project which could share the model code basis with the web app (java script), so I have started a little java / gradle based project, where I simply want to "translate" a `Model` class into javascript.

```
public class Model {
  public String foo;
  public int anInt;

  public String fancy(){
     return foo + anInt;
  }
}
```

My code is organized like this:

```
-src
    -main
        -java
            -com
                -tickaroo
                        -Model.gwt.xml
                        -shared
                            -Model.java
```

In my build.gradle I use [this gradle plugin](https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'gwt-compiler'

gwt {
  gwtVersion = '2.7.0'

  compiler {
    strict = false;
    enableClosureCompiler = true;
    disableClassMetadata = false;
    disableCastChecking = false;
    style = 'DETAILED';
  }

  modules 'com.tickaroo.Model'
}
```

`Model.gwt.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
  <source path="shared" />
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
</module>
```

I compile it using `./gradlew compileGwt` which generates the gwt stuff like `5F23E45D7ECEA3E7E1FBCB3E0CF8B557.cache.js`, `com.tickaroo.Model.nocache.js`, etc.

Well, I thought I could get somehow the javascript translated `Model` class to work and access it "natively" in javascript:

```
 <javascript>
    var model = new com.tickaroo.shared.Model()
    model.fancy()
 </javascript>
```

Is that possible with GWT? How does Google's Inbox team managed that? Does anyone know how to do that in GWT or any additional sources like blog posts?

The idea is to have a common (partial) business logic layer for android , web and later for iOS (j2objc). We have a complex syncing algorithm, and we want to make a syncing layer or call it library if you want to with a public api. The idea is to have this syncing library written once and translated to web and iOS platforms. the public api of this library would allow to "inject" platform specific dependencies like persistent layer (DAOs). So there will be handwritten javascript code that should interoperate with the generated syncing library javascript code.

I have found a GWT plugin called [gwt-exporter](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) which seems to do something similar. However, this is not under active development and I would avoid using such third party things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is an optimizing compiler. It prunes everything (classes, fields, methods) that's not referenced from the `EntryPoint`s, does all sorts of optimizations (method inlining, etc.) and obfuscates everything in the end to produce the smallest possible JS script. It's primarily meant for applications, not libraries.

gwt-exporter is being replaced with [JsInterop](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tir74SB-ZWrs-gQ8w-lOEV3oMY6u6lF2MmNivDEihZ4/edit) but it's still alpha quality right now (JsInterop V1 should come in 2.8, in spring this year). JsInterop will make GWT more suited for JS libraries and hybrid applications (like Inbox). The Inbox team probably relied on JsInterop, but they also used a fork of the GWT compiler with custom features for better integration with Closure (GWT generates JS with Closure annotations), so it's likely not the JsInterop that we can use nowadays "from the outside".

Comment: No, both GWT and Dart have a feature called JsInterop.

Comment: Is the JsInterop alpha version available for public? I couldn't find it

Comment: In GWT 2.7 or 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT, turn it on with `-XjsInteropMode JS`.